# Void not working outside viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, void, viewdidload

I'm beginning iOS programming and I'm stuck with calling a
void method.

*Please don't tell me that `MKReverseGeocoding` is deprecated. I know that. I need to use xcode 3.4 and IOS 4, so, I have no choices. (32 bits computer).*

I have made this simplified void method:

```
-(void)getAdress
{
    CLLocationDegrees lat=37.4217080;
    CLLocationDegrees lon=-122.0829964;            
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);        
    MKReverseGeocoder *reverseGeocoder=[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];
}
```

If I call this void method from `viewDidLoad`, the address is found and I can see it in the console in plain text.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
        ............
    [self getAdress];
}
```

But if I try to do it from another void method it doesn't work. I have tried many things but the console never shows the address, although I can see the NSLog message "Trying to get adress" in the console...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    ...................
    NSLog(@"Trying to get adress");
    [self getAdress];
}
```

The reverseGeocoder methods i use :

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)reverseGeocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"The geocoder has returned: ERROR%@");
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)reverseGeocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {
    NSLog(@"Reverse Adresse : %@", [placemark addressDictionary]);
}
```

Comment: The problem definitely isn't what you think it is... You can call a method that returns "void" from any method. Where/how are you trying to log the results?

Comment: Please take the time to read some basic programming books like the "C" programming language. Oh, `void` just says that the method does not return anything, you are not calling nor do you have a `void`.

Comment: @Zaph But in all fairness, though the OP is clearly confused about some things, the issue you brought up is obviously just a problem with semantics. If you go through the OP's question and replace "void" with "void method," your objection wouldn't hold. In fact, I'll make the edit now.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. I simply use the console to see what's happening. If I use [self getAdress] inside viewDidLoad brackets, the console is showing the address. This is not happening if I use it in another void method.

Comment: Could you share your implementation of the reverse geocoder's delegate methods (`-reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark:` & `-reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError:`)? Also, using breakpoints would help you to get a better insight into your flow and possibly find the root of the problem.

Comment: I'm assuming there is another `NSLog()` somewhere that shows the address? If you pass an empty string into an `NSLog()` then nothing will be printed in the console. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be your reverseGeocoder var goes out of scope at the end of getAddress method.  This might cause for the object to be deallocated before you receive the response.

One thing you may consider doing is using an ivar instead of local variable.

Comment: Trying to declare MKReverseGeocoder *reversegeocoder as an ivar in the .h file but no changes at this time. Maybe it's my declaration... I need to read some more documentations. I feel you have the good answer but i can t confirm it for now.